# Programming Dot Probe for Psychopy in Builder

Tags: functional-programming, psychopy, probe

I am new to using PsychoPy and I have programmed a few simple tasks. I am currently really struggling to program a word dot probe. I do not want to use coder, simply because the rest of my research team need to be able to easily edit the program, and work and use it.

In case anyone is wondering what my specific problem is, I cannot seem to get the pictures to load at the same time correctly and do not know how to get a probe to appear behind one of the pictures once the pictures have disappeared.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say that the pictures do not load at the same time, do you mean that there e.g. is a 100 ms. delay or that they do not show simultaneously? Do your words have to be pictures and not ``TextStim``? You can use a picture or the ``Polygon`` stimulus to draw a circle/dot. I imagine having a routine with two textStims and starting t=0 and then offset at the desired stimulus duration, followed by the onset of the dot and then waiting for a keyboard response. I.e. a routine with four components.

Comment: Yes I mean there is a delay for the pictures to appear. So I have a 500ms fixation cross, then the stimuli appear simultaneously for 500ms. However there is delay in them loading which means that they only actually appear for around 100-200ms. Also I have two separate programs one using imageStim (for the face dot probe) and the other uses TextStim (this one loads fine and appears for the correct amount of time). I'm mainly struggling with getting the probe to appear in a counterbalanced manner. The probe can appear in two different positions and should do so with equal probability.

Comment: With respect to image delay: Try putting an ISI period during the 500 ms fixation. This will allow for the images to load in the background (I hope - haven't used it myself). I assume that you have a separate image component for each image location in the routine. With respect to probe probability, this is one of the cases that the current TrialHandler does not handle well. You may have to generate the dot location using a code component. I'll post an answer if you think this is a way forward.

Comment: Thank you so much! The ISI period has worked perfectly and the pictures now load during the fixation cross period, allowing them to appear on time! Also I think using a code component to change the position of the dot would be the best way forward, if you have an answer or any other suggestions, they are greatly appreciated! Thank you for all of your help

Answer (score 1):

## Timing

The timing issue can be solved by inserting an ISI period in the beginning of the trial, e.g. during a fixation cross. This allows psychopy to load the images in the background so that they are ready for presentation.

## Truly random dot position

In your case, you want the dot position to be random, independently of image. This is one of the cases that TrialHandler does not handle and I suspect you need to insert a code component to make this work. For true randomness but only 50% probability in the limit of infinite trials, simply put this in a code component under "begin routine":

```py
x = (np.random.binomial(1, prob) - 0.5) * xdist
y = 0
dot.pos = [x, y]
```

and change `dot` to the name of your dot stimulus, `y` is the vertical offset, `x` is the horizontal offset (here varying between trials), `xdist` is the distance between the dot positions, and `prob` is the chance of the dot appearing to the right. You probably want to set this to `0.5`, i.e. 50 %.

## Balanced dot position

If you want the dot to appear at each side exactly the same number of times, you can do the following in the code component:

Under "begin experiment", make a list with the exact length of the number of trials:

```py
dotPos = [0, 1] * int(round(numberOfTrials/2))  # create the correct number of left/right (coded as 0 and 1). [0,1] yields 50%. [0,0,0,1] and /4 would yield 25 % etc.
np.random.shuffle(dotPos)  # randomize order
```

Then under "begin routine" do something akin to what we did above:

```py
x = (dotPos.pop() - 0.5) * xdist  # dotPos.pop() takes returns the last element while removing it from the list.
y = 0
dot.pos = [x, y]
```

Naturally, if the number of trials is uneven, one position will be occupied one more time than the other.

## Two dot positions for each condition

For the record, if the dot position is to be shown at each position for each image-combination, simply count each of these situations as conditions, i.e. give them a separate rows in the conditions file.